# Am I able to extend the InputMethodService but use a default keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create a app that just extends the default InputMethodService. If I do this, will I be able to use one of the default keyboards so I don't need to grab the whole package and make my own keyboard? I just want to override one method in the InputMethodService so that all keyboards use this overriden method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to override one method in the InputMethodService so that all keyboards use this overriden method.

This is not possible.

Comment: thanks for the response! I guess I'm trying to do something similar to a Spell Checker where you can process text from the editable text while or at the end of a commit. The spell checker comes from this api Manager... TextServicesManager. On http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textservice/TextServicesManager.html it says under the Text Service Sessions, The spell checker session is one of the text services... does that mean there are more or should I just extend a spell checker?

Comment: @alex: That I don't know, sorry.